# Unknown module(s) in QT: charts - Error while building QGroundControl for Android

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator, qtcharts, qgroundcontrol

I am trying to build the QGroundControl for Android with the QT, but I am getting the below error:
error: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts

**I can build the QGroundControl for Windows without any trouble.**

I am using **Windows 8.1 x64**.

[image: About QT Creator]

[image: available kits]

[image: Detail of android kit]

[image: android device detail]

**Error Message:**

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add

```
QT += charts
```

in your .pro file.

If you want to use charts just in android use

```
android: QT += charts
```